# Broken packages in package manager

Tags: linux-mint

I am attempting to setup linux mint 18.1 Cinnamon on my computer, however I am repeatedly encountering a lot of issues with the package manager.
A lot of the packages cannot be installed as they are apparently broken. For example, in order to install a program with a dependency on the package libgtk2.0-dev, I obviously need to first install the package. Yet when I mark it for installation in the package manager, it fails as the package is apparently broken.

Before marking for installation:
[image]

After marking for installation:
[image]

This seems to be a common problem for a lot of the packages in the package manager, and I'm unsure how to proceed or even how to view why the package is supposedly broken so I can look in to fixing it.

apt-cache policy:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial/partner i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Canonical,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=i386
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial/partner amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Canonical,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=amd64
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://packages.linuxmint.com serena/backport i386 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=backport,b=i386
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 500 http://packages.linuxmint.com serena/backport amd64 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=backport,b=amd64
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 500 http://packages.linuxmint.com serena/import i386 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=import,b=i386
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 500 http://packages.linuxmint.com serena/import amd64 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=import,b=amd64
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com serena/upstream i386 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=upstream,b=i386
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 700 http://packages.linuxmint.com serena/upstream amd64 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=upstream,b=amd64
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 500 http://packages.linuxmint.com serena/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=main,b=i386
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
 500 http://packages.linuxmint.com serena/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.linuxmint.com
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: What version/release of Linux Mint is it? And please provide some details of the problems you are seeing, including transcripts of your session, otherwise the question is likely to be closed. If you already have the OS installed, please provide the output of `apt-cache policy`. In the question, not as a comment.

Comment: There aren't really transcripts, as far as I'm aware, instead the GUI just shows the package as broken and doesn't show why. Everything else I've updated the OP with.

Comment: Oh, you're using `synaptic`. You'd really be better off using a command like tool like Debian's `apt`. For installation you'd mostly be using `apt-get`. Is the installation forcing you to use `synaptic`, or are you choosing to do so?

Comment: I'm new to linux, so was just trying to stick with what seemed easy in order to keep things simple. If something else is better then I have no problem using it.

Comment: None of this should be happening in the first place. Why are you trying to install this package? If it is because something else depends on it, just install the something else and it will bring in its dependencies automatically.

Comment: I see you are mixing Ubuntu sources with the Mint sources. Does the installation guide suggest this? If not, I suggest you avoid doing this, at least till you are more familiar with how these things work.

Comment: I'm attempting to install an IDE (codelite 10.0), which is meant to be compatible with LM, however the installation fails as the package on which it depends (mentioned in the OP, libgtk2.0-dev) cannot be installed.

Comment: I don't follow. Are you using the Ubuntu sources because you want this IDE?

Comment: I'm guessing you're referring to what's in synaptic? If that's bad I'm sorry, I made that mistake since I'm new and I just assumed it was correct since that's what synaptic defaulted to.

Comment: I'm referring to your sources. See `/etc/apt/sources.list` and also the files under `/etc/apt.sources.list.d`. Did you add any entries to those files? Oh, and if you want someone to be notified of a comment, you need to add @username to your comment.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I don't know if I did, as while I did not intend to do anything like that, I might have done it in my inexperience.